# Recursive function crash in C++

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I'm told by an online friend that this should work (shouldn't crash), but he hasn't given me any actual advice how to fix this..
Apologies if this question is overly simple, I'm still a beginner!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int f(int n)
{
if((n-1)==1) return 1;
else return 2*f(n)-n;
}

int main()
{
cout<<f(1)<<endl;
cout<<f(1)<<endl;
cout<<f(0)<<endl;
cout<<f(-3)<<endl;
cout<<f(-10)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `f` supposed to do?

Comment: `f(n)` calls `f(n)`. You pass the same parameter as argument, **unchanged**. When exactly should it stop?

Comment: For anything other than `n==2` this will just infinitely call `f(n)` until something breaks.

Comment: (n-1)==1. That's a rather strange way of saying n==2. Unrelated to your problem however, which has been pointed out already by others.

Comment: @Bilkokuya - Quite the opposite if the shop has any sort of code review process

Comment: Think also about the *mathematical* equation `f(n) = 2*f(n)-n` ....

Comment: If `(n-1)==1` is false (i.e. if `n != 2`) a call of `f(n)` calls `f(n)`.   That is infinite recursion.

Answer (score 10):

Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), improve your code to get no warnings, then **run your program *step by step* in a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

You'll discover -when using the debugger- that you have an infinite recursion, since `f(n)` is calling `f(n)`.

When coding recursive functions, beware of excessive [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) depth. As a rule of thumb, each individual call frame should be less than a kilobyte, and the entire call stack is limited to about a megabyte (or a few of them). Details are implementation and operating system specific.

Be also aware that some [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (including recent `g++` when invoked with `-O2` or better) are able to optimize *some* [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) into iterative code.